# url rewrite with string in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, urlencode

I am trying to use mod_rewrite to redirect users keeping the multiple query string and creating a redirect page

For Example,
If user opens

```
http://localhost/url/url/http://www.google.com/contacts/?user=abc&stackoverflow=great&google=facebook
```

then he is taken to

```
http://localhost/url/url.php?redirect=http://www.google.com/contacts/?user=abc&stackoverflow=great&google=facebook
```

There is secondary problem that URL should be encoded and then redirected! If URL is not encoded then the string (&stackoverflow=great)would be not a part of 'redirect' string of     url.php

I tried many solutions then came for stackoverflow! I tried the following code in following file

```
 http://localhost/url/.htaccess 

RewriteRule ^url/([^/])$ url.php?redirect=$1 [QSA,L]
```

but the result is localhost/url/url.php?redirect=http only

Comment: So what _have_ you tried so far? We caanot help with your issue if you don't post your attempts.

Comment: Encoding that 'inner' url is out of scope of the rewriting module. It must be done by whatever generates that url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup won't work with the unencoded inner url, so an 'answer' can only have temporary character. But this might be a starting point:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/url/url/(.*)$ /url/url.php?redirect=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I wonder however if that fragment `/url/url` is really intended (the *two* 'url's in there).

Note that the exact rule content also depends on *where* you want to define that rule. The syntax is different whether you use the central server configuration (referred) or `.htaccess` style files (as second choice and more complex).

Comment: http is neglected...
http://localhost/url/url/http://www.google.com/

goes to http://localhost/url/redirect.php?redirect=www.google.com

Comment: As already said: this cannot work without encoded 'inner' url. Simply because the first  url you give out is illegal, it violates the syntax rules. So it is up to the client (the browser) to _guess_ what might make sense. Encode the inner url!

Comment: And frankly, I _doubt_ this calls a script `redirect.php`, did you really try this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect ^url/url/(.*)$ url/url.php?redirect=$1
```

The basic redirect systax,

redirect accessed-file URL-to-go-to